# How does war application (java) knows how to respond on requests

Tags: java, request, jax-rs

Currently learning the web developlent using Jave EE. And I have a question.

For example I made a java class, using JAX RS, where I explicitly provide @Path annotation, so that the application now can respond on such a request as : @Path("/helloworld") - site.com/helloworld

But how does it understand that it needs to load index.html if request comes to site.com, and no annotations are set up?
The same question with loading images, when the request comes because of html: .

What should I read to udnerstand more about the question?

EDIT: my web.xml is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the Servlet spec to understand how web applications work in j2ee. 
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `web.xml` file. It probably has something like this:

```
...
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the welcome-file tag in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

From there you can use a simple forward :

```
request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request,response);
```

Or you can use server side templating to build the html file and pass html back to the client etc etc. The welcome file is the key here to telling your application where to go when no servlet has been sent with the request.